# About Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet's effect + pay cost for no effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Chronomaly_Cabrera_Trebuchet):

> Once per turn: You can Tribute 1 other "Chronomaly" monster, then
>   target 1 face-up monster your opponent controls; its ATK becomes 0
>   until the End Phase.

- Player A has on field Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet, and 1 more Chronomaly monster, so total of 2 monsters on his field.
- Player B activated Enemy Controller and took control of Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet.

**Q1:** It says `You can Tribute 1 other "Chronomaly" monster,..` without specifying which side of the field, so player B can tribute player A's other Chronomaly monster to fulfill this cost, right?

**Q2:** For any card in YGO, can you fulfill a cost without doing the effect? Like in this case, player B wants to fulfill the cost of Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet by tributing player A's monster, but player A doesn't have any more monsters to change their attack to zero. Can player B still activate Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet's effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1:
No you can't. You can only pay for costs with your own cards (so cards you control, in your grave/deck/hand...).
There are some cards that allow this, but it will be stated explicitly on the card.
E.g. the kaiju monster or 'chimeratech fortress dragon'.

Q2:
Won't work in this specific scenario for above reason, but to answer in general, this is also not allowed.
In the case of 'Chronomaly Cabrera Trebuchet' the reason is that as part of the cost, you need to target a monster on your opponents side of the field, so if there are none you cannot activate the effect.
To give a bit more obvious example of this, you can't activate 'Monster Reborn' if there's no monster in either players graveyard.